# rider удаляет табы и пробелы

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ide, jetbrains, rider

rider удаляет пробелы и табы в коде

например с этого

```
.Include(x=>x.)
    .ThenInclude(x=>x.)

.Include(x=>x.)
.ThenInclude(x=>x.)
```

делает такой формат

как можно это отключить?

Comment: `x=>x.` по идее даже не скомпилируется, вы проверяли с синтаксически верным кодом?

Comment: я пример написал как пробелы удаляет. кода здесь как пример без переменных

Comment: вдруг он удаляет, потому что синтаксические ошибки в коде? я же не знаю, поэтому и спросил, все ли так же для компилируемого кода?

Comment: И правильно удаляет. Потому что у этих методов один уровень вложенности. / P.S. Семантически уровень разный, но синтаксически - один.

Comment: ну проект старый и если я начну рефакторить будет проблема